# How to swap variables pointing to data, without swapping their content?

Tags: vector, rust

Is it possible in Rust to swap 2 vectors (without shadowing previous variables), by making them point to each-others in-memory representation?

I'm porting some code from C, which is quite straightforward when dealing with pointers.

Pseudo-code (C-like):

```
float *a = malloc(size);
float *b = malloc(size);

error = calc_params(curve, a);
for (i = 0; i < REFINE_ITER_MAX; i++) {
    /* reads 'a', refines to 'b' */
    calc_params_refine(curve, a, b);
    error_test = calc_params(curve, a);
    if (error_test < error) {
        /* How to do this in Rust??? */
        float *swap = a;
        a = b;
        b = swap;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

The code above refines one array into another, using source/destination arrays which are swapped each step.

Given two vectors which are the same length and use primitive types (`float`/`i32`/`usize`... etc), how would this be done in Rust?

---

From reading `mem::swap()` documentation, its not clear to me how this applies to `Vec` types: *"Swap the values at two mutable locations of the same type, without deinitializing or copying either one."*

For all I know, the vectors could be resized in-place and data copied between them - while still fitting the description given.

Comment: Also: your example has more details than it needs to have. You could just replace those `calc` and `refine` methods by comments explaining what happens. The loop isn't really necessary either. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess a good question would be: "I've googled and found `mem::swap()`. But I'm not sure if it swaps the contents of my vectors or just the pointers, like in my C-example."

Comment: Yes, I had read about `mem::swap()` and used it in some cases, but its wording and example doesn't make it totally clear that for large data-structures, the constant doesn't isn't swapped. (shows 2 int's being swapped). For example, the docs say *"Swap the values at two mutable locations of the same type, without deinitializing or copying either one."* - It would be possible to write a swap function that fits this description, that swaps data byte by byte (just without running a Copy)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt, you're probably right, in this case I wasn't sure how much to simplify, sometimes when over-simplifying, it makes it un-clear why an operation is being done and answers may not fit the actual use-case. - for example, shadowing could be used to swap variables if it wasn't in a nested scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) is doing exactly what you want. Take this example:

```
let mut a = vec![/* fill this vector */];
let mut b = Vec::new();

loop {
    // do something ...

    std::mem::swap(&mut a, &mut b);
}
```

`swap` doesn't touch the vectors' contents at all. It just swaps the raw bytes on the stack (this includes the pointer to the data as well as the length and capacity field). It really is "swapping names".

Comment: It's not swapping names, e.g. if you replaced the `vec`s with fixed-size arrays it would be copying. The works because `vec` is (mostly) in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Rust has a `std::mem` module containing a number of functions for such use cases.

In this case you are interested in [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html), which exchanges the content of two given objects.